# Rest Api Wordpress

Tags: plugin-development, rest-api, cookies, authentication

I wrote little plugin and I tried to use Rest Api of Wordpress for to communicate admin page to my rest. My problem is : failed rest_cookie_invalid_nonce, return 403 always.

My ajax call :

```
const form_information_user = jQuery('#form-information-client-login')[0];

let formData = new FormData(form_information_user);

formData.append('_wpnonce',obj_php.nonce)

jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url : obj_php.ajax_url_login,
    cache: false,
    async: true,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    data: formData,
    success: function( data ) {
        // Azioni da eseguire in caso di successo chiamata
        console.log("success: ",data);
    },
    error: function( error ) {
        // Azioni da eseguire in caso di errore chiamata
        console.log("error: ",error);
    }
});
```

My php file to show view :

```
class Wp_Diet_Admin_Dashboard{


    private string $plugin_name;
    private string $version;

    public function __construct(string $plugin_name, string $version) {

        $this->plugin_name = $plugin_name;
        $this->version = $version;


        $this->load_scripts();
        $this->load_styles();
        $this->set_scripts_variables();
        $this->load_dashboard();

    }

    public function load_dashboard(): void
    {
        require_once plugin_dir_path( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . 'views/wp-diet-admin-dashboard.php';
    }
    

    public function load_scripts(): void
    {
        wp_enqueue_script( $this->plugin_name . '-just-validate.js', plugin_dir_url(dirname(__FILE__) ) . 'js/just-validate.js', array('jquery'), $this->version, true );
        wp_enqueue_script( $this->plugin_name . '-dashboard.js', plugin_dir_url(dirname(__FILE__) ) . 'js/dashboard.js', array('jquery'), $this->version, true );
    }

    public function set_scripts_variables() : void
    {

        $obj_php = [
            "ajax_url_registration" => URL_API_V1 . 'form_information_user_registration',
            "ajax_url_login" => URL_API_V1 . 'form_information_user_login',
            "required" => __('Questo campo è obbligatorio','wp-diet'),
            'nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'wp_rest_dashboard_login' ),
            "error" => __('Valore non valido per questo campo','wp-diet'),
            "error_email" => __('Email non corretta','wp-diet'),
        ];

        wp_localize_script($this->plugin_name . '-dashboard.js','obj_php',$obj_php);

    }        
}
```

My php file route

```
class Wp_Diet_Admin_Api{

    private string $plugin_name;
    private string $version;
    private WP_REST_Server $server;

    public function __construct(string $plugin_name, string $version) {
        $this->plugin_name = $plugin_name;
        $this->version = $version;
        $this->server = new WP_REST_Server();
    }

    public function load_routes( ): void
    {

        register_rest_route(
            NAMESPACE_V1,
            'form_information_user_login',
            array(
                'methods' => WP_REST_Server::CREATABLE,
                'callback' => array($this, 'form_information_user_login'),
                'permission_callback' => '__return_true',
            )
        );
    }  

    public function form_information_user_login(WP_REST_Request $request)
    {
        $body = $request->get_body_params();
        $email = sanitize_email($body['email']);
        $pass = sanitize_text_field($body['password']);

        $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

        $req = $client->request('POST', 'http://www.localhost:3000/registration-success', [
            'form_params' => ['email' => $email, 'password' => $pass]
        ]);

        //jwt-licenza / messaggio d'errore
        $response = json_decode($req->getBody()->getContents(), true);

//        wp_send_json('ok');
        print_r(wp_get_all_sessions());

    }
}
```

If I not use nonce argument in body request it work but I can't know if the user is logged in, if the request is legal, and I can't manage a session for saving a jwt.

I would like to recognize who is the user who sends me the request and if it is possible to insert the saving of a jwt with relative refresh

Any advice is welcome, thanks for help

Best regalds,

Edit 1:

I try use wp_verify_nonce and the functions failed auth because user in rest api is nobody meanwhile in ajax call the user is logged user. I think is correctly approach, but in this ways I don't know how check auth or user or permission callback.

Answer (score 0):

- Check caching/plugins interference
- Try using:

jQuery.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url : obj_php.ajax_url_login,
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
xhr.setRequestHeader('X-WP-Nonce', obj_php.nonce);
},

- Check that nonce is actually set correctly in the hidden form field and when submitting check the payload in dev console, make sure the key/value match i.e, nonce_check: e7chadas0d
- Lastly, double check you have it setup according to https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/

Comment: Thank your for you time and reply, I tried insert nonce in body, in header, and guide suggest by Wordpress relative cookie auth. Nonce is correct, I print nonce before ajax call and after and it's equal

Comment: @tecnico57, try posting this to https://wordpress.org/support/forum/wp-advanced/ it's for advanced WP development, you'll maybe get more luck there.

Comment: Okay I will try, Thanks :)